# How to distinguish between two WebElements with the same id?

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have two fields with the same id on a single HTML page (using Angular)
How to I distinguise between the two without creating a collection and referring to the indexes>

An example of one field is below

I've tried this

```
#content-container > inv-sidebar-layout-content > ng-component > ng-component > section > div.row.tab-container > as-split > as-split-area:nth-child(1) > article > inv-people-tabs > inv-vertical-tabs-list > div.tab-content-container > div > inv-tab:nth-child(7) > div > inv-people-contact-details-tab > section > div.left-column > inv-person-contact-details > section > inv-address-edit > section > div:nth-child(2) > input
```

but it's too long and cumbersome

The HTML for the first field is

```
<input _ngcontent-gec-c113="" class="inv-input" id="towncity" formcontrolname="TownCity">
```

and for the second it is

```
<input _ngcontent-gec-c113="" class="inv-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="towncity" formcontrolname="TownCity" ng-reflect-name="TownCity">
```

Comment: You should find a way to make each `id` [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9454645/1009922).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme

Comment: @ConnorsFan That's nice if you own the site or can advocate for that fix but some people don't have that option.

Comment: Need more context on those two elements. Why is the same TownCity element appear on the page twice? Is it desktop vs mobile versions? Is it two different forms, each of which have it? You need to find an element in the ancestors that is different (preferably with an ID) and use that to distinguish them, e.g. `#mobile #towncity` vs `#desktop #towncity`.

Comment: Agree 100% with @ConnorsFan. The site is currently not W3C compliant HTML, it should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements have different classes so you can distinguish them using [`class` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp)

Example selectors:

1. First element:

   ```
   //input[@id='towncity' and not(contains(@class,'touched'))]
   ```

   [image]
2. Second element

   ```
   //input[@id='towncity' and contains(@class,'touched')]
   ```

   [image]

More information:

- [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: In general, yes but I'm guessing that those classes are tracking state so they may appear/disappear and leave the element locator unable to find it.